# Excel - Remove duplicate row if column value is null

Tags: excel

If I have 3 rows in Microsoft Excel with the following data

```
id      name     address  
id01    john     rundown avenu

id02    bill     maptown drive

id01    john     null
```

What is the easiest way to remove the third row because id01 already exist AND already has an address?  Formula or ribbon buttons...I don't care how.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways you could do this including a vba procedure. However, one easy way without needing VBA would be to use the next available column to mark rows for delete. If this was column D using the example above then you would paste the following formula into cell D2:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)>1, C2="null")
```

This can then be pasted down the remaining rows. The A$2 reference will remain the same (because of the dollar) and the other A2 references will change relative to the cell they are pasted to.

You can then set auto filter, to only the true records, delete these rows and then unfilter.

Let me know if you would prefer an automated solution as the VBA for this would also be pretty straight forward.